# Help with js function explanation - Why $this = $(this)...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A user called "mu" as provide me the following answer that I really like. 
However, I do have some questions here, and I hope anyone could help me out.

Given the following:

```
function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('orig', $this.html()).html('<a href="blabla.org">go here</a>');
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.data('orig')).removeData('orig');
    }
```

**1)
Why do we have the need, and what does it do:
var $this = $(this) - Why can't we use $(this) all over the place?**

**2) Why do we need the 'orig' thing there?**

Please, :) provide as much detail as possible, really, I'm quite new on all this.

Thanks a lot in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `$this` instead of `$(this)`, but it will be faster. You are making the call `$(this)` once and storing the result in a variable instead of doing the call over and over again.

Note that `$(this)` is a call to the function `$` with the value of `this` as parameter, while `$this` is just the name of a variable. The function call returns a jQuery object that contains a list of the one element that `this` refers to, so that's what's stored in the variable.

The string `'orig'` is an identifier for the piece of data that you are storing. Each piece of information that you store using the `data` method needs an identifier.

Comment: @krof: I couldn't agree less. I really hate those docs. A lot of information... yes... but the writing and the explanations... and the way the information architecture was put in place there... arrhg. STILL, I have to read it of course, and more often. As an example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ (I don't understand why do I need almost the same information twice). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using jQuery.

```
var $this=$(this)
```

just puts the value of the jQuery function into a variable (called $this), saves a little time as it's not calling the function to get the value when used later.

jQuery objects use the "data" property to hold data.  it is a key/type of property.  so a line like

```
$(this).data('orig', whatever);
```

creates a key called "orig" in the data property and puts the value "whatever" in it.

Comment: data is a property? (I thought it was a method or function). I was thinking that having something that accepts arguments, (normally with the () syntax) that I was in face of a method or function but never a property. Guess I have to read more...

Comment: yes, you are right.  sorry.  it is a function to store and retrieve data by name. I always think of it as a property since it is behaving like a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $(this) all over the place but there is always overhead in converting an element to a jQuery object, so if you know you are going to be using a jQuery object multiple times, and not in a chain, then you should store it as a variable so you don't incur the overhead in jQuery conversion every time.

The orig part just stores the original content of the node so it can be returned to the original state after its finished. Similar to storing it in a variable but you don't have to worry about scope.